# javascript transform text array

Tags: javascript

I use a react component which work like this

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```

it take a font awesome icon let say address-book it add fa before, delete hyphen and uppercase the first letter of each world.

```
   address-book become faAddressBook
   copyright become faCopyright
   arrow-alt-circle-down become faArrowAltCircleDown
```

Is it possible to create a javascript function which take an array like this

`["address-book","copyright","arrow-alt-circle-down"]`

and transform it in an array like that

`["faAddressBook","faCopyright","faArrowAltCircleDown"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do it. Like using regular expression. However, your requirement is simple, so it can be easily done with JavaScript split method. Please check the following implemented function.

```js
function formatArray(str) 
{
    str = str.split("-");

    for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i < x; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
    }

    return 'fa' + str.join("");
}
var givenArr = ["address-book","copyright","arrow-alt-circle-down"];
for( var i = 0; i < givenArr.length; i++) {
  givenArr[i] = formatArray(givenArr[i]);
  console.log(givenArr[i]+ '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with **Array**'s `map()` and `forEach()`:

```js
var arr = ["address-book","copyright","arrow-alt-circle-down"];

function upperCase(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

var outPut = arr.map(function(item){
  var temp = item.split('-');
  var temp2 = [];
  temp.forEach(function(data){
    temp2.push(upperCase(data))
  });
  return 'fa' + temp2.join('')
})
console.log(outPut);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's two essential steps here. First, we need to prepend `fa` onto each string, and second, we need to convert them from kebab-case to camelCase.

So just write a function for each of those conversions, then run your array through a map using each of them:

```js
const kebabs = ["address-book","copyright","arrow-alt-circle-down"];

function kebabToCamel(str) {
    return str.replace(/-(\w)/g, m => m[1].toUpperCase()); 
}

function prependFa(str) {
    return "fa-" + str;
}

console.log(kebabs.map(prependFa).map(kebabToCamel))
```